# Cannot get validation only to fire for Antd form with Formik - errored fields only show when actually trying to submit

Tags: reactjs, antd, formik

I'm having trouble getting my form, which is an Antd Form, to validate only (without submitting), by clicking a button, rather than submitting it.  The only way to get it to validate and update the fields with errors is if I try and submit it.  Is there a way to do this?  Or am I stuck having to submit the form?

I have a button for submission and one for validation only - the validate only button calls the validateForm method, but nothing ever updates on the form.

**EDIT**: **here's a link to codesandbox to demonstrate this**: https://codesandbox.io/s/xo5ln7l32p ...again - when I touch the textbox or click the submit button, the validation works and shows the error message underneath the textbox, however, when clicking Validate All by itself, no error is displayed underneath the textbox.

*Here is my code for my base Antd Form:*

```js
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Form as AntdForm } from 'antd';
import FormValidationAlert from './FormValidationAlert';

function Form({ children, onSubmit, isValid, validationErrors }) {
  return (
    <AntdForm layout="vertical" onSubmit={onSubmit} style={{ margin: 20 }}>
      {!isValid && <FormValidationAlert validationErrors={validationErrors} />}
      {children}
    </AntdForm>
  );
}

Form.propTypes = {
  onSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  isValid: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  validationErrors: PropTypes.array
};

export default Form;
```

*Here is my form:*

```js
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Formik } from 'formik';
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import { Col, Row, Steps } from 'antd';
import {
  Form,
  TextInput
} from '../common/forms';

class CreateItemForm extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const formik = {
      initialValues: {
        name: ''
      },
      validationSchema: Yup.object().shape({
        name: Yup.string().required('Name is required.')
      }),
      onSubmit: (values, actions) => {
        this.props.onSubmit(values);
      }
    };

    console.log('this.props', this.props);

    const { setFormRef, status, currentStep } = this.props;

    return (
      <Formik
        ref={setFormRef}
        {...formik}
        render={form => (
          <Form
            onSubmit={form.handleSubmit}
            isValid={status.isValid}
            validationErrors={status.validationErrors}
          >
            <TextInput
              {...form}
              name="name"
              placeholder="Name"
              label="Name"
            />
            <button type="button" onClick={() => validateForm().then(() => console.log(blah))}>
              Validate All
                    </button>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
          </ Form>
        )}
      />
    );
  }
}

CreateItemForm.propTypes = {
  onSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  status: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  setFormRef: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default CreateItemForm;
```

*Here is my TextInput:*

```js
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Form, Input } from 'antd';
import ReactInputMask from 'react-input-mask';

function TextInput({
  values,
  errors,
  touched,
  handleSubmit,
  setFieldValue,
  setFieldTouched,
  name,
  label,
  placeholder,
  disabled,
  addOnBeforeValue,
  addOnAfterValue,
  mask,
  maskPermanents
}) {
  return (
    <Form.Item
      label={label}
      hasFeedback={!!errors[name]}
      validateStatus={touched[name] && errors[name] && 'error'}
      help={touched[name] && errors[name]}
    >
      {mask ? (
        <ReactInputMask
          disabled={
            disabled === null || disabled === undefined ? false : disabled
          }
          alwaysShowMask={false}
          value={values[name]}
          onChange={event => setFieldValue(name, event.target.value)}
          onBlur={() => setFieldTouched(name)}
          mask={mask}
          permanents={maskPermanents}
        >
          {inputProps => (
            <Input
              {...inputProps}
              placeholder={placeholder}
              onPressEnter={handleSubmit}
              addonBefore={addOnBeforeValue}
              addonAfter={addOnAfterValue}
            />
          )}
        </ReactInputMask>
      ) : (
          <Input
            disabled={disabled}
            placeholder={placeholder}
            value={values[name]}
            onChange={event => setFieldValue(name, event.target.value)}
            onBlur={() => setFieldTouched(name)}
            onPressEnter={handleSubmit}
            addonBefore={addOnBeforeValue}
            addonAfter={addOnAfterValue}
          />
        )}
    </Form.Item>
  );
}

TextInput.propTypes = {
  values: PropTypes.object,
  errors: PropTypes.object,
  touched: PropTypes.object,
  handleSubmit: PropTypes.func,
  setFieldValue: PropTypes.func,
  setFieldTouched: PropTypes.func,
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  label: PropTypes.string,
  disabled: PropTypes.bool,
  placeholder: PropTypes.string,
  addOnBeforeValue: PropTypes.string,
  addOnAfterValue: PropTypes.string,
  mask: PropTypes.string,
  maskPermanents: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.number)
};

export default TextInput;
```

Comment: pelase provide an working fiddle.

Comment: Added a link to codesandbox to show what I mean.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out - it wasn't showing the errors because the Form.Item in the TextInput was checking for the field to be touched first:

```
<Form.Item
      label={label}
      hasFeedback={!!errors[name]}
      validateStatus={touched[name] && errors[name] && 'error'}
      help={touched[name] && errors[name]}
>
```

...changing this to the following allows this to work (I just remove the check for whether the field was actually touched):

```
<Form.Item
      label={label}
      hasFeedback={!!errors[name]}
      validateStatus={errors[name] && 'error'}
      help={errors[name]}
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can validate for button click instead form submit.
Some points you should consider.

1. You should wrap the form elements with  tag.
2. Don't forget to use the export method wrap with create form method.

   `export default Form.create()(SimpleForm`);
3. add a onlick method and use validate method like below.

   this.props.form.validateFieldsAndScroll((err, values) => {
           if (!err) {
               //Do something what you want.
           }
       });
4. Use proper validation method for fields

Good luck!

Comment: Problem is that I'm using Formik with this, so I wouldn't be using the Antd Form component this way.

Comment: Ok, I don't have experience with Formik, But I am sure Antd is the best framework and it will cover almost requirement, since I have successfully completed 3 different projects with Antd

Answer (score 0):

On validate all button click, you could use `form.submitForm();`

You can check here with  working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/validate-form-button-click) demo.

**Code snippet**

```js
function doSave(values) {
  console.log("saving data", values);
}

function validateAllClick(form) {
  form.submitForm();
  console.log("just validating");
}


function App() {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <h1>Here's My Form</h1>
      <Content>
        <CreateItemForm
          status={editModelStatus}
          setFormRef={setFormRef}
          onSubmit={values => doSave(values)}
          onValidate={validateAllClick}
        />
      </Content>
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

Comment: I unfortunately cannot do this because if the form is valid, it'll be submitted, and I don't want that, I only want validation, and if it is valid, do not submit it (just do nothing else).